# Google reCaptcha error

Tags: php, mysqli, recaptcha

Code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'KEY';
        //get verify response data
        $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        echo var_dump($responseData);
        if($responseData->success){

            //contact form submission code

            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass");
            if (!$connection) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
            }
            $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "database");
            if (!$db_select) {
                die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
            }
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $regHour = date('d-m-Y H:i');
            $order = "INSERT INTO `database`.`pre_register` (id, email, register_time) VALUES ('', '$email', '$regHour')";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $order);    
            if($result){
            echo "OK";
            }
            else{
            echo "error";
            }
        else    {
     echo 'Please check the reCAPTCHA box.';
     }

}
```

It doesn`t work. If I check the reCaptcha and complete the email, it gives me "Error". If I complete the input email and do not check reCaptcha, it gives me the error "Please check the reCAPTCHA box."

I would really appreciate a little help. I can't figure it out why it gives me Error message. The db connection parameters are ok. I double checked them.

`echo var_dump($responseData);` shows message: "NULL Please check the reCAPTCHA box."

Comment: call [mysqli_error()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp) to find out what the error ist.

Comment: It Looks like the id is a autoincrement. you chould remove it from your insert Statement ` $order = "INSERT INTO `database`.`pre_register` (email, register_time) VALUES ('$email', '$regHour')";`

Comment: I tried to call mysqli_error() but it does not show errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're missing a `}` (or 2) bracket from the bottom.

update the following bit

```
if($result){
            echo "OK";
            }
            else{
            echo "error";
            }
        else    {
     echo 'Please check the reCAPTCHA box.';
     }

}
```

to the following

```
    if($result){
                echo "OK";
                }
                else{
                echo "error";
                }
        } else    {
            echo 'reCAPTCHA is invalid';
        }
    }else {
        echo 'Please check the reCAPTCHA box.';
    }
}
```

Also please update the request made with `file_get_cotents()` from

```
$verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
```

to a `curl` request

```
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE); 
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$responseData = json_decode($curlData, TRUE);
```

full code (with a little formatting)

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
        //your site secret key
        $secret = 'KEY';
        //get verify response data
        // $verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);

        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, TRUE); 
        $curlData = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        $responseData = json_decode($curlData, TRUE);
        if($responseData['success'] == 'true') {

        // $responseData = json_decode($verifyResponse);
        // if($responseData->success) {

            //contact form submission code

            $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass");
            if (!$connection) {
                die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
            }

            $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "database");
            if (!$db_select) {
                die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error());
            }

            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $regHour = date('d-m-Y H:i');
            $order = "INSERT INTO `database`.`pre_register` (id, email, register_time) VALUES ('', '$email', '$regHour')";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $order);    
            if($result){
                echo "OK";

            } else {
                echo "error";
            }

        } else {
            echo 'reCAPTCHA is invalid';
        }
    }else {
        echo 'Please check the reCAPTCHA box.';
    }
}
```

Comment: If I complete the email and check reCaptcha now, it sends me straight to last error.

Comment: @Bogdan what does `var_dump($responseData)` right before `if($responseData->success) {` return. Could you please update your question with the `var_dump` results

Comment: @Bogdan i have updated my answer to make a `curl` request instead of `file_get_contents()` (please see full code bit). Could you try that one please?

Comment: I tried it. If I complete email and check reCaptcha, it is ok, but if I do not check reCaptcha, I do not get any error, just the normal page.

Comment: @Bogdan that's a bit strange, try `if($responseData['success'] === true) {` instead of `if($responseData['success'] == 'true') {`

Comment: @Bogdan is that fails `var_dump($responseData)` right before `if($responseData['success'] == 'true') {` post results please

Comment: I know it is strange. I tried until 05 in the morning to solve a simple google reCaptcha and I did not figured it out... My head hurts, trust me. :))

Comment: Same thing. If I do not check reCaptcha, It shows me normal page, without errors. Maybe my host has something disabled in php.ini?

Comment: @Bogdan it doesn't return any errors even when you don't fill the recaptcha? If you have it uploaded, may i have the link please?

Comment: @Bogdan Have had my share of stupid weirs stuff with code so i know the feeling :) hehe

Comment: http://couriero.eu/ -> I did not had so many headaches with my platform and I have with this Captcha. It is checkbox type.

Comment: http://www.codexworld.com/new-google-recaptcha-with-php/ - >this is the code I copied and it is working on their test page.

Comment: @Bogdan I have updated my answer. Please try with the final code bit. There was one `else` missing for when `$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` was not set or empty. I believe it should show the error now when reCAPTCHA is not set.

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. Although, in IE. 11 it does not show the error message. I echoed the error message as variable. But it is OK in the end because now it is working fine, especially on Android. Thank you very much. Merry Christmas and all the best from Romania. :)

Comment: I did a thumb up to your post, but when I will have +15 reputation, it will show. :)

Comment: @Bogdan Glad i could help you..Happy Holidays & all the best from Maldives :)

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks for the +15 or you could select as correct answer..i will also update the answer to reflect what later helped :) Cheers and good luck